# Sort html list ascending

Tags: html, sorting

What is the best way to sort this list

```
<ul id="keywords_list" class="list-unstyled list-filter list-filter-singleline">
    <li class="keyword_row" id=0>
        <input class="key_checkbox" id="0" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="25"><a href="#" class="key_link" id="25"><span class="label label-default transition"><span class="keyword" id="0">8</span></span><i class="icn icn-checkmark"></i>Dogs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="keyword_row" id=1>
        <input class="key_checkbox" id="1" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="16"><a href="#" class="key_link" id="16"><span class="label label-default transition"><span class="keyword" id="1">5</span></span><i class="icn icn-checkmark"></i>Cats</a>
    </li>
    <li class="keyword_row" id=2>
        <input class="key_checkbox" id="2" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="3"><a href="#" class="key_link" id="3"><span class="label label-default transition"><span class="keyword" id="2">5</span></span><i class="icn icn-checkmark"></i>Birds</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The output should be like this:

```
<ul id="keywords_list" class="list-unstyled list-filter list-filter-singleline">
    <li class="keyword_row" id=2>
        <input class="key_checkbox" id="2" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="3"><a href="#" class="key_link" id="3"><span class="label label-default transition"><span class="keyword" id="2">5</span></span><i class="icn icn-checkmark"></i>Birds</a>
    </li>
    <li class="keyword_row" id=1>
        <input class="key_checkbox" id="1" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="16"><a href="#" class="key_link" id="16"><span class="label label-default transition"><span class="keyword" id="1">5</span></span><i class="icn icn-checkmark"></i>Cats</a>
    </li>                                             
    <li class="keyword_row" id=0>
        <input class="key_checkbox" id="0" name="keywords[]" type="checkbox" value="25"><a href="#" class="key_link" id="25"><span class="label label-default transition"><span class="keyword" id="0">8</span></span><i class="icn icn-checkmark"></i>Dogs</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried some of the examples on StackOverflow but they didn't work.

Comment: So you want to sort the list items by their `ID`? You'll have to use JS for that.

Comment: Not by their ID but by the value (Birds, Cats, Dogs), alphabetically

Comment: You'll still have to use JS.

Comment: need to know more about your stack, are you using a database to output the list? Can it be sorted server side? Can it be output as a JSON doc and sorted via JS? If there are predictable sorted queries can you sort on the server output with each sort as it's own independent JSON and then cache them in RAM? As the saying goes there are many ways to skin a cat.

Comment: If it's just hardcoded HTML then your only option would be to use javascript. Cache the DOM, read the values into an array, sort the array based on first letter, write back to the DOM. You can watch [this series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoYCgNOIyGABs-wDaaxChu82q_xQgUb4f) on modularJS and it should help you in understanding these things (also why Jquery is bad).

Comment: I will try, thank you!

Comment: Actually it is a collection from laravel controller output by foreach function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use JQUERY to sort by getting the `li's` text.

source: http://www.onemoretake.com/2009/02/25/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

> It utilise the javascript array.sort method to sort the elements in
>   the array and then using the jQuery append() method,  reorder them in
>   the actual list element.

```
$("#sort").click(function() {
  var mylist = $('#keywords_list');
  var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
  listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
  })
  $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) {
    mylist.append(itm);
  });
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6573s7h8/4/)**

Comment: This function adds bunch of li elements at the top of the page not where it should be on the page, when put in window.onload function